# EJB3 Interceptor- Setting attributes and reading them on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, ejb-3.0, interceptor

In an enterprise application, I'm trying to set some attributes in an EJB3 interceptor and then show them on a jsp. Is it possible? How can I achieve that? The use case is as follows- Some values are read from the database which are required to be shown on the error page. This error page is the default error page, no controller for it. I couldn't find anything in the code regarding this error page, nothing in web.xml. Need a solution for this asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to use an interceptor. I ended up using a filter, which was already there in the application. I set an application scope variable map in the init method of the Filter. That ways, I had to get and set the values only once, i.e., at the server startup. Then I used this map in the JSP to read the values. Like, ${applicationScope.appParams.someKey}.